# Simple Powershell Msbuild with parameter fails

Tags: powershell, msbuild

I am trying to pass a simple variable passing,

No parameter

```
msbuild MySolution.sln /p:Configuration=Debug /p:Platform="Any CPU"
```

Try 1

```
$buildOptions = '/p:Configuration=Debug /p:Platform="Any CPU"'
msbuild MySolution.sln + $buildOptions
```

-> cause MSB1008

Try 2

```
$command = "msbuild MySolution.sln" + $buildOptions
Invoke-expression $command
```

-> cause MSB1009

I tried the solution on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/809333/powershell-command-processing-passing-in-variables) post but I think it is a different error.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try one of these:

```
msbuild MySolution.sln $buildOptions

Start-Process msbuild -ArgumentList MySolution.sln,$buildOptions -NoNewWindow
```

By the way, there's a new feature in PowerShell v3 just for this kind of situations, anything after --% is treated as is, so you're command will look like:

```
msbuild MySolution.sln --% /p:Configuration=Debug /p:Platform="Any CPU"
```

See this post for more information:
http://rkeithhill.wordpress.com/2012/01/02/powershell-v3-ctp2-provides-better-argument-passing-to-exes/

Answer (score 1):

You need to put a space somewhere between `MySolution.sln` and the list of parameters. As you have it, the command line results in

```
   msbuild MySolution.sln/p:Configuration=Debug /p:Platform="Any CPU"
```

And MSBuild will consider "MySolution.sln/p:Configuration=Debug" to be name of the project/solution file, thus resulting in `MSB10009: Project file does not exist.`.

You need to make sure that the resulting command line is something like this (note the space after `MySolution.sln`:

```
   msbuild MySolution.sln /p:Configuration=Debug /p:Platform="Any CPU"
```

There are plenty of ways to assure that using Powershell syntax, one of them is:

```
   $buildOptions = '/p:Configuration=Debug /p:Platform="Any CPU"'
   $command = "msbuild MySolution.sln " + $buildOptions # note the space before the closing quote.

   Invoke-Expression $command
```